# Can eagle autoroute same signal on two layers?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, routing

I am trying to construct a PCB in Eagle v7.4.0 Light where some tracks are 220 V tracks. They are in a net class of its own.
Question is, can I tell eagle to mark these tracks/ratsnest lines to be automatically routed on both sides of a double-sided-pcb? (I want to use both sides for same signal, that way I can make the line thickness half of what it should be)

Comment: thouh shalt stay away from autorouting for useful results

Comment: why don't you manually route these traces first, before anything else?

Comment: I have played with earlier versions of the autorouter and I don't believe there is any point trying; whenever the problem is in any way complex, it takes much more time to persuade it to do what is needed than do it by hand. Further, if the tracks are 220V they should be most probably be segregated. So I'd be very tempted to put barrier polygons between them and the rest of the tracks. IMHO tcrossley is correct

Comment: @Plasm: That's a gross overreaction.  Like any tool, you have to learn to use it well.  If you do, you can get good results and have it take care of the grunt work of routing for you.  I've used it on dozens of professional projects quite affectively, but then I took the trouble to learn how to use it properly, and don't expect it to just solve everything for me.  It's not a complete solution, but is a useful tool.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Maybe it improved in recent times, but whenever I tried it I had to fix so many things that it was essentially necessary to check for every trace by hand if it was layed out good, which sometimes amounts to even more work than doing it myself. I don't know for what specific circumstances you use it, but maybe you had just better cases of constraining it. Might be useful for you to ask and answer a question about "when to use autorouting in eagle and when not" since about everyone I met has similar feelings about eagle autorouting.

Comment: @Plas: No, the basic autorouter doesn't seem to have changed much since version 4 when I first started using it.  Again, you really have to *understand* it, learn what all the tweaks do, and experiment with them to get some intuition.  Too many people seem to put no effort into it, use the defaults, then blame the tool when they get the inevitable mess.  It's a very useful tool once you learn to use it well.

Comment: I have used the autorouter with some success, by applying @tcrosley's suggestion. Route the 'important' tracks by hand first, back that file up (to mitigate undo problems with the autorouter), then use autoroute. It can be more useful than simply routing signals; for example it can show places where poor component positions or orientations are making routing harder. However, we were new to Eagle, and it took us *days* of experiments to get anything we considered worthwhile. Further, because it seems to be an art, discovered through exploration, we weren't convinced we'd adequately explored it.

Comment: Thanks guys. You have comfirmed my suspition. Autoroute or not, well, with my two week experience in routing, autoroute is a great tool. I have found that if you just place the components 100% correct and tweek the router good, you will have good results. The placing of components though, is not my strong side :) 
I will use your suggestions to (auto)route the mains first, then do the rest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't believe the Eagle autorouter can do that.  You can set a trace thickness in the net class, but I don't know of any way to have the autorouter realize that thickness by using several thinner tracks.

As a side note, just because the tracks carry high voltage doesn't mean they need to be thick.  In fact, high voltage usually implies lower current, so if these are the tracks feeding AC into a power supply that puts out a lower DC voltage, they don't need to be as fat as those DC tracks.  The issue with high voltage is distance from other tracks.  This is also set in the net class and will be obeyed by the autorouter.

The Eagle autorouter is a decent tool that can be used to good affect, but it can't do everything for you, and you absolutely have to get really familiar with it for good results.

Comment: Thanks @olin Lathrop. Yes, I am aware that 220V not directly implies high amps, but for this little experement I'm looking at up to 5A. I will go for the assumption (and probably true) that eagle doesn't automatically route on both sides, and do this part first, them route the rest auto or nonauto